# Regarding timers in embedded C

Tags: c, timer, embedded, avr

So I am having my exam tomorrow. I missed a lecture but I have a recorded professor's lecture. During the lecture, the professor mentioned that we will need to know how Timers work within embedded procesors.

I have a basic understanding, however I am confused on the Math part. Professor said that for example he will give us a 12-bit timer running at some rate X. We will have to set the timer value initially and wait for it to overflow. If we want the timer to wait for 3 miliseconds, what do we set the timer to?

In addition, professor said that "it is a simple math, giving us clocks equal to 1,000,000 and the time will be 1000 so we can do divisions easily."

Can somebody please explain how timers exactly work and what would I need to do in order to get the math part correctly.

Comment: "If we want the timer to wait for 3 miliseconds, what do we set the timer to?" You are essentially asking "how fast is a CPU".

Answer (score 4):

Most embedded timers work as follows:

- set timer to some initial value, T
- start timer
- timer decrements once per timer clock
- when timer reaches 0 (or underflows beyond 0) an interrupt is generated

So the elapsed time will just be `T / timer_clock_rate`, where T is the initial timer value and `timer_clock_rate` will depend on how you've configured the timer.

So for example if you want a 3 ms delay and your timer clock rate is 1 MHz (i.e. the timer decrements once every 1 µs) then you need an initial timer value of 3000 (3000 x 1 µs = 3 ms).

**EDIT:** see also @Rev1.0's answer - apparently AVR timers count up rather than down - note that some other micro-controller families use count down timers. The same general principle applies to both however, but the initial constant that you would load will be different depending on whether you are counting up or down.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you Paul

Comment: A lot of timers count up to a trigger value or overflow. Good timer peripherals will be able to do both depending on need. The question does mention waiting for an overflow, so I would imagine the timer in question is an upcounter as well.

Comment: speaking generally and not avrs, some up, some down, some you have control over up vs down.

Answer (score 2):

While Paul's example maybe sufficient for you to get the idea how it works, it addresses the problem somewhat different from what your question suggested.

The mentioned overflow occurs when the timer reaches the maximum value. That would be 4096 for a 12 bit timer (2^12). Having a given clock of 1MHz (1us per tick) you have to count to 3000 to get 3ms like Paul already pointed out.

So you would set the initial value of the timer to 4096 - 3000 = 1096 to get an overflow after 3ms.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I didn't know that the AVR timers counted up rather than down (a lot of other micro-controllers use count down timers).

Comment: All AVR devices I came to know use count up timers. There are several PWM modes that use a combination of counting up and down, but as far as I know, the normal counter direction can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the dimensions.  X is cycles per second, assume that one tick is one cycle (if there is a prescaler, then there is another adjustment here, the timer counts in ticks).  And one second is 1000 milliseconds.  so just arrange all of these dimensions so that they cancel out leaving only the one you want

```
1 tick     X cycles   1 second            3 milliseconds
-------- * -------- * ----------------- * -------------- 
1 cycles   1 second   1000 milliseconds
```

cancel out all the units divided by themselves.  from grade school math (almost) anything divided by itself is one, just apply that to units.  leaving:

```
1 tick    X     1       3 
------ * --- * ----- * --- 
1         1    1000
```

So whatever your timer clock source frequency is in cycles per second (Hz) is multiplied by 3 and divided by 1000.  If that clock frequency is 1000000 then (1000000*3)/1000 = 3000.

That is how you can easily figure out what is multiplied and what is divided, works for every flavor of conversion.  Miles per hour to kilometers per second, whatever.

then just follow Rev1.0's answer or Paul R.

Sometimes there is an N-1 thing you have to be aware of which is either documented or you can test for.  For example if you have a down counter the docs will/should say if the timer rolls over or interrupts WHEN it reaches zero or AFTER, usually they are AFTER, when the actual roll over happens, so 3000 to 0 inclusive is 3001 counts, you are off by a little, so for a system like that you need to program the timer with 2999 to get 3000 ticks.  For an up counter it is usually one of two ways, it counts from zero to the programmed value, same deal count from 0 to 2999 to get 3000 counts so you would probably program a 2999 in the register not 3000.  Or the value you program is the start count as Rev1.0 showed, and the rollover is after the all ones value for whatever the register size is, in this case they tell you 12 bits which is 0xFFF, dont make the 0xFFF - 3000 mistake and get 1095, easy to do it the way Rev1.0 shows (0xFFF+1)-3000 = 4096-3000 = 1096 that is your start count.

Same goes for prescalers, you have to be very careful to read what they are saying do you program a 2 to divide by 2 or program a 1 to divide by 2?  What happens if you program a 0 is that a divide by 1 or invalid or a divide by the max value, or an invalid divisor setting?  Where does that fit into the dimensional analysis?  ticks / cycles.  A prescaler that divides by 8 means that for every 8 cycles you get one tick, so that is a 1 tick / 8 cycles.

Now sometimes you will have a system clock that divides down for the peripheral clock and the the peripheral clock is what feeds the timer, then you may have a prescaler there so n system clocks / 1 peripheral clock, then 1 peripheral clock / 1 timer clock, then 1 tick is M timer clocks.  Get everything lined up so all but one cancels out and there you go.

You can do this in reverse as well and will and should.  From the numbers we have right now 3000 timer ticks is 3ms or 0.003 seconds.  3000/0.003 is ticks per second or cycles per second of 1000000.

But what if we had a different controller or one with a clock we didnt know (or we have a crystal we know but we suspect there is a prescaler somewhere we cant find in the docs) so let the timer roll over 4096 ticks for example, we measure that with a stopwatch or oscilloscope or something, not that accurate in either case but might give us a rough enough idea to figure out if there is a prescaler or what clock we are actually running on if there is a pll multiplying the clock, etc.  Say it was 0.0005 seconds for every 4096 timer ticks, 4096/0.0005 = 8192000 hz.  Now if the crystal/oscillator in the schematic or we can read off of the part says 16Mhz that would make some sense 8000000/4096 = 0.000512 and 8Mhz is half of 16Mhz, so your measurement is probably off by a smidge and the clock has some accuracy as well and may be off by some amount.  So you check the docs to see if there is an internal oscillator, if not then you are probably running off of the 16Mhz clock but there is a divide by 2 that is documented and you have not found it or isnt documented (it happens some times) and your timer is running off of system clock/2.  Now you can use that number as X and figure out whatever you need.  Why not have the timer count to 1000 or some other number that is easier to compute.  that is fine too, but can take more work and more experiments, sometimes you have a free running timer you cannot reset at a some max or min count and instead you can just say

```
while(1)
{
while((read_timer()&0x1000)==0) continue;
turn_gpio_on();
while((read_timer()&0x1000)!=0) continue;
turn_gpio_off();
}
```

Measure the on time or the off time and that is 0x1000 ticks.  hex not as pretty a number as 1000 decimal when doing decimal math on your calculator, but it is pretty when you can simply use an and operation with one bit to toggle the gpio/led.

This last point being, you can read the docs and schematics and think you know how it is working, but you should test your results, and if you are off by some whole multiple, esp if it is a power of two either your math was wrong by some whole number or there is a clock divisor somewhere in the chip you dont know about or have not looked hard enough to find, this could also mean you may have thought you boosted the crystal speed to some other speed using the pll, and maybe there is a mistake there and everything in the chip is not running at the desired speed.

(if this answer is useful to you then upvote Paul and Rev1.0 before upvoting me, thanks, just expanding on their answers).